# Gtsummary table values less than -1 outputting as 1.00?

Tags: gtsummary

Since installing the newest version of R, all my gtsummary table  values less than -1 have been outputting to 1.00. Does anyone have insight on how to fix this very weird issue?

Here is example code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gtsummary)
library(haven)
library(mice)
library(googlesheets4)

data <- read_sheet("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yyw-0xseZSLjD4jc8sw7IksN-S0M3vcKWHy4ksMPL4c/edit?usp=sharing")
  
datami <- mice(data,  m = 23, seed=10)

datareg <- with(datami, 
                lm(SUD ~ NUM + MIND + 
                     AGE + SEX  + CRAVE) )

table <- tbl_regression(datareg,
                        estimate_fun = purrr::partial(style_ratio, digits = 2),
                        pvalue_fun = ~style_pvalue(.x, digits = 2),
                        add_estimate_to_reference_rows = TRUE
) %>% modify_header(label="**Predictor**",estimate="**Unstandardized Coefficient**") %>%
  modify_footnote(update = c(p.value, ci, estimate)  ~ "Reference group")%>%
  modify_caption("Table: Multiple Imputation Predicting Variable")
table
```

Have re-installed R & gtsummary multiple times to no avail.

Comment: Can you please update your post to 1. Read the CSV file from google drive directly, so we don't need to futz with file paths and downloads, 2. please make your example as minimal as possible: only include lines of code essential for illustrating your issue.

Comment: also, please clearly indicate the estimate from the model you see an issue with.

Comment: Thank you! I've made those fixes. The issue is seen multiple times in the table; first, it is seen as the unstandardized coefficient & 95% CI values for the NUM predictor.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `style_ratio()` to round/format the estimates: this is meant to round odds ratios, risk ratios, etc., which are all positive numbers. Update this to use `style_number()`.

I should update the ratio function to have better behavior when negative values are passed.